# I am getting redirected to google brazil, what is this, malware in my browser / server?

Tags: virus, malware

Not sure if this is a malware in my server or browser, but a few days ago a client of mine complained that when he searched for a given site (Courfleurie[dot]com) in google, and then click on that link in Google's result page, instead of going to the site, he is getting taken to Google.com.br page.

I couldn't reproduce that, and neither another friend whom I asked to have a look.

This morning, client sent me a google link, which when I clicked I went to a google page and then when I clicked on the first link.

http://www.google.fr/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=courfleurie.com&oq=courfleurie.com&gs_l=hp.3..0i10j0i30l2.2970.6115.0.6777.15.12.0.3.3.1.438.2766.0j3j5j2j1.11.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.w9RZAUiCuss&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.d2k&fp=40c7a5d5e06b6bb9&biw=1236&bih=622

It's happenning in my FF & Safari and not in Chrome.

Any thought on this, anyone ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a problem. Just a simple one time error. Or a one link error in Google's results. Definitely not worth a question on Stack unless it's doing it in more than ONE place.

Comment: So a website is probably affected by a malware, stopping people to access the site through Google and you think it's not a problem !!!

Am I missing something, or it's just Google's problem and we can't do anything here ?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing about this scenario that screams malware. If there was, though, you should check out http://security.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: Thanks Josiah, I will probably ask the question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like server-side malware, I bet it's a joomla or wordpress site

Answer (score 0):

Google handles redirects based on the geo-location of the requesting IP address.  This is most assuredly a random failure, assuming you're not obscuring your source IP using [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/%E2%80%8E) or something.